# «В городе Ленинграде» или «в Ленинграде»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, выбор-слов, стилистика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно говорить: «Я родился в городе Ленинграде» или «Я родился в Ленинграде»? Интересует именно использование слова «город», потому что где-то я читала, что его не употребляют в этом контексте.

Answer (score 3):

Из **[ПИСЬМОВНИКА](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)** на **Грамоте.ру**:

В «Справочнике издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К. Чельцовой указано, что «сокращение г. (город), как и полное слово, рекомендуется употреблять ограниченно, главным образом перед названиями городов, образованными от фамилий (г. Киров)».

Таким образом, общеупотребительно: в Москве. Варианты в г. Москве, в городе Москве  следует характеризовать как специфически-канцелярские (т. е. употребительные преимущественно в официально-деловой речи). **Варианты в г. Москва, в городе Москва не соответствуют литературной норме.**

Comment: Про Ленинград спрашивают, а вы про Москву говорите. :))

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае употребление родового слова (город) не очень уместно. Вот "Я родился в городе Кологриве Костромской области" - здесь вполне уместно. Разницу чувствуете?